# LINQ Where condition against datatable

Tags: linq, datatable

I have a DataTable. I would like to filter DataRows where City = "Hongkong".

How to apply LINQ against DataRow?

Comment: You need [LINQ to DataSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following Query

```
var filter = testTable.AsEnumerable().
                       Where(x => x.Field<string>("City") == "HongKong");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var result = dr.Where(r => r.Field<string>("City") == "Hongkong");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [LINQ to DataSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx), you can do the following:

```
DataTable table;

var rows =
    from row in table.AsEnumerable()
    where row.Field<string>("City") == "Hongkong"
    select row;
```